# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]

Tags: android, android-studio

When I click to run a project I just created in Android Studio 0.2.10 and select my Android (connected by USB with debug by USB on) I get this error:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: 0123456789ABCDEF
Uploading file
    local path: /Users/Rui/AndroidStudioProjects/FirstAppProject/FirstApp/build/apk/FirstApp-debug-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/rui.firstapp
Installing rui.firstapp
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/rui.firstapp"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/rui.firstapp
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
```

Any Idea of what it might be?

Comment: Select my phone...!! Did you mean emulator...??

Comment: No, my Android with debug by USB on.

Comment: Did you make sure that the app is compatible with the device you are using? Check the `MinSDK` and `TargetSDK` values in your manifest. Have you tried installing this in an emulator? This will narrow down whether the problem is with the APK or your device.

Answer (score 186):

I was getting this in Android Studio and all I did to fix it was go to `"Build" > "Clean Project"` and it just worked.

Comment: If it's still not working, Build -> Rebuild Project after Clean Project would work.

Comment: I just got this with an update from gradle 5.4.1 to 5.6.1 - not sure what strangeness caused it but big gradle upgrades certainly can. An alternative command-line solution is `./gradlew clean` followed by your normal build command

Comment: I was getting this issue because I changed my project path, `"Build" > "Rebuild Project"` worked for me.

Answer (score 44):

Just remove old APK android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk in the folder. 
that's all. enjoy your coding...

Comment: `rm -fr android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/`

Comment: Isn't it the same than doing a clean?

Comment: There is no build directory in "app". What can I do?

Answer (score 15):

i got similar issue once, what i observed was, package name in my Androidmanifest.xml was started with one empty space character. `like " com.example.test" instead of "com.example.test"`

I removed all such invalid spaces from my manifest file, it solved my problem

**Edit 1**: '-' in package name also cause same issue on some android versions

Comment: Wow! I thought  `invalidate cache and restart` would force a clean build, apparently it doesn't.

Answer (score 14):

If someone is still having issue then **Build->Clean** Project then **Build->Rebuild** project finally **Sync project with Gradle file**.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem but none of the solutions worked for me. The problem was that I had no **.** separators in my package name. 
i.e. if your package name is **my.packagename** its fine but it can't be just **mypackagename**
Got the hint from this bug report.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55841

Answer (score 10):

Navigate to `Run/Debug Configurations`

Click Run from the top Tab > Edit Configurations

- Module: Select your App
- Installation Options: Deploy Default APK
- Ok

[image]

Answer (score 8):

How to solve this issue:

1. Install `RootExplorer`
2. Create new `tmp` folder on SD card
3. Long press on tmp folder, and select `Link` to this folder (last option in menu)
4. Go to `/data/local/` and tap button `CREATE LINK` from bottom

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue and none of the above solutions worked for me.

For some reason, the permissions weren't set correctly on my `/data/local/tmp` directory (only root had rwx). I fixed the issue using ADB (you'll need a rooted device):

1. Connect your phone via USB
2. Launch ADB using `adb shell`
3. Move to `/data/local` using `cd /data/local`
4. Switch to root mode using `su`
5. Allow read/write/execute on `tmp` directory using `chmod 777 tmp`
6. Disconnect, restart Android Studio and plug in device again

Answer (score 7):

By turning off the **Instant Run** solved my issue. Don't know any explanation till now. After migrating to android studio 3.0 it starts problem like this. Hope this helps someone in future.

Answer (score 6):

When I experienced this issue, what fixed it for me was making sure that the AndroidManifest.xml package name was the same as the build.grade applicationId.

Answer (score 5):

I tried most above offered solutions (the simple ones, not those offering chmod and altering internal libraries) and none of them work

Eventually what worked for me was:
"Clean Project" -> "Rebuild Project" -> changed the app versionName in the build.gradle app module -> Sync Gradle -> Run the app on the device

Comment: This method worked for me!! Thank you so much, I had been struggling with this for a long time, this is a life saver indeed! Can't thank you enough

Answer (score 4):

try these commands:

```
cd android
```

then

```
./gradlew clean
```

then

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 3):

I found another reason of this error. If you rooted your device access permissions of /data/local/tmp may be changed, so adb can't get access to it temp file. Solution is to create "tmp" folder on sdcard and create symlink to it in /data/local/ (via ADB shell or Root Explorer).

Comment: I couldn't believe that: cross-checked with another device (all permissions seemed identical, up to the root level); fiddled with the permissions (made them 777 even) – no way. So what to lose. Tried the symlink – wow! Works (+1). I'd still like to know why and what's behind that. It was not rooting causing it in my case, but making the ADB daemon run in "insecure mode" (i.e. with root permissions).

Answer (score 3):

If you write `android:extractNativeLibs="false"` in AndroidManifest file. then change it to `android:extractNativeLibs="true"`

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue by having mismatched build variants. A Dynamic Delivery module was on the debug variant while the remaining modules were on release. Simply changing the Dynamic Delivery module to release, rebuilding, and installing, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

For Flutter projects, with VS Code editor, go to the project source folder and delete the "build" folder and start debugging.

Comment: Thanks, your solution fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on android Studio because in my Debug build i've added version name suffix **-DEBUG** and the **-** was the problem.

#### Try to only have letters, numbers and dots on your version names and application ids

Answer (score 2):

This helped in my case:

```
Settings -> Apps -> Google Play Store -> Click "Enable" button.
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I disabled the GooglePlay and didn't notice this was the root cause of my issues.

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue on a project with Dagger and multiple modules. What worked for me (none of the above worked) was to 
1) empty the .gradle folder 
2) empty the .idea folder
3) In project gradle.properties, mark org.gradle.caching=false
4) Possibly invalidate caches in AS, clean, rebuild

You may be able to get away with just #3, clean then build.

EDIT: Lately I've been able to get around this by restarting AS, then doing a clean, then install again.

Comment: strangely. i have tried some above. this worked for me
This android development is getting crazy. code for 30 secs and wait for 5 mins to get the build

Comment: @satyajit . 5 mins!! mine takes 10!

This is the only one that consistently works for me.

Comment: i am able to make it work with `./gradlew installDebug` from the command line

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this problem for me was having the wrong build variant selected for one of my app's modules. From the "Build Variants" tool, I selected the module variant which matched the app module, and it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

After a great update, check that the `applicationId` of the `build.gradle (Module: app)` and the package in `AndroidManifest.xml` are identical.
I had the same problem and so I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently had this problem building a multi-module, multi-apk application. As it turns out, my top level gradle build was modifying the `android:versionCode`, and that was making it out of sync with the manifests in the dynamic feature modules. This took me hours to find the cause, and only minutes to solve.

I found that the android studio log itself,

> idea.log

, tells me way more about the problem than the IDE did.

```
2020-02-05 22:52:56,206 [thread 246]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - Failed to commit install session 986623974 with command cmd package install-commit 986623974. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: /data/app/vmdl986623974.tmp/1_mytestapp-afat-debug version code 1829 inconsistent with 18290 
2020-02-05 22:52:56,206 [thread 246]   WARN - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - Install failed: The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK The APKs are invalid.
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the previous version if installed already and try again.It might help

Comment: But this was the first time I run it therefore there nothing to uninstall

Comment: try adb remount then install

Answer (score 0):

I have used the androidquickstart maven archetype and faced the same problem:

My package name was an only androidquickstart. According to advices before

1. I have changed the package to androidquickstart.test
2. then in AndroidManifest.xml I have changed `package="androidquickstart"` to `package="androidquickstart.test"` and correspondingly removed test from other parts of xml `<activity android:name=".test.HelloAndroidActivity" >` to `<activity android:name=".HelloAndroidActivity" >`
3. and also fixed package issues in java files (highlighted by the IDE)

Answer (score 0):

I just had same error. I had year 2015 in app id. I replaced 2015 by fifteen and that solved it.

Also, if you use Android Studio, you can try:
Tools / Android / Synch Project with Gradle Files

Answer (score 0):

**Force Stop** the application in the device settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and none of the above solutions worked for me.

The reason is probably root version phone that has available quota or apk install permissions only at the sdcard.

I fixed the issue using ADB (you'll need a rooted device):

1. Connect your phone via USB
2. Launch ADB using adb shell
3. Switch to root mode using su
4. create tmp folder in the sdcard: mkdir /sdcard/tmp
5. cd /data/local
6. create link the the folder in the sdcard: ln -s /sdcard/tmp tmp

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be multiple reasons for this failure.
For me, the issue was that in AndroidManifest file I had referenced a non-existing library(only in this particular device) using the 'uses-library' tag.
After removing the library which this device did not have the apk got installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your package name should include words combined by dots like com.example or prashant.mydairy..... it should work fine now

files  where you must update  ur package name are as below:
1)Manifest file
2)Gradle file(module appp):
applicationId "package.name"

Comment: should be comment

Answer (score 0):

taskAffinity name must have at least one '.' separator

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the device console (adb shell), then change permissions of following:

1. chmod 777 /data/
2. chmod 777 /data/local/
   You might also want to try copying the apk to `/data/local/` in which case, **make sure the set the right permissions to the apk** also.
3. chmod 777 /data/local/myapk.apk
   You can now attempt an installation by:
   pm install -r -d /data/local/myapk.apk (note the absolute path)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like having a number after the **dot** was the culprit.

I had the same issue with the following applicationId

```
org.tony.stark.125jarvis
```

Changing it to

```
org.tony.stark.jarvis
```

I was able to install the app to the android devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if the `minSdkVersion` in `builde.gradle` is bigger than the device's Android version. In that case you have to modify the `minSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

delete code in AndroidManifest.xml:

tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" android:appComponentFactory=""

it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I get this error `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]` when I try to install apk with `pm install -r -d /sdcard/Download/foo.apk`.

Since this package already uninstalled by `pm uninstall <foo_package_name>`, I try delete `/data/local/tmp/<foo_package_name>` but no luck.

I need **reboot the android** system to fixed. (Not sure remove `data/local/tmp/<foo_package_name>` step is necessary or not.)

**[UPDATE]**

It happen again just now, I try do not uninstall since I need to keep the apk inherit sdk 22 permission, so this time I use `am force-stop <fook_package_name>` to stop it first, then retry `pm install`, it fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the similar issue, but it auto fixed after i reboot my Ubuntu PC，for I install some Ubuntu(12.04)app update,which leads to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue in android studio 3.4. By turning off the Instant Run solved my issue. Don't know any explanation till now.  Hope this helps someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what exactly causes the issue. 
A had several schemes, all could be build and install all of them and once, one didn't want (after what actions - don't know). In all unknown situations I execute:
`npm run mac-reinstall`
where in `package.json` in `scripts` section:
`"mac-reinstall": "rm -rf -v package-lock.json ios/build ios/Podfile.lock android/.gradle android/build android/app/build node_modules && npm i && cd ios/ && rm -rf Pods/ && pod install && cd ../"`
You can try to leave only Android's part from the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple modules project with multiple flavors and each flavor has a different `applicationId` then you have to make sure that all your modules are targeting the same build variant.
[image: Active Build Variant from Android Studio]

Answer (score 0):

if build clean doesn't work then check your build variants whether all the modules have the same variant.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem with this message

> Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install adb:
> failed to install ~\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure
> [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in
> /data/app/com.example.weather_flutter-Azzrb6hHi67p7xfzCG6lyA==:
> Package
> /data/app/com.example.weather_flutter-Azzrb6hHi67p7xfzCG6lyA==/base.apk
> code is missing] Error launching application on SM A105F.

And the solution worked for me was
deleting all file on this project directories `build\app\outputs\apk\debug` and `build\app\outputs\flutter-apk` and every thing went perfect from there

Answer (score 0):

For those who might still be having this problem, You can cleaning, rebuilding and invalidating caches does not work, couple of things to try;

1. Upgrade Your gradle build version to the latest version.
2. If your code is kolin, check Kotlin version used for building with Gradle is same from the one bundled into the IDE plugin. Upgrade to that bundled into the IDE
   Then sync.
   I upgraded to android studio Arctic fox 2021, ha this issue, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I updated my Android Studio to Artic Fox, this kept happening on my app flavours.

To be able to run the app again I needed to unnistall, clean and invalidate-crashes.

So I decided to update my version to Bumblebee, and now everything works without needing to invalidate-crashes, clean or unnistall my app.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30912370)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a flutter app and I just deleted the "/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk" file. I rerun it and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

> Run/Debug Configurations

Click Run from the top Tab > Edit Configurations

- Module: *Select your App*
- Installation Options: > Deploy Default APK
- Launch: > Default Activity
- Ok

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2EzG.png)