# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK] on building and deploying android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build

I'm developing an android application on Android Studio, it was working fine but recently it has been throwing the following error. Any ideas on how i can solve it?

**EDIT:** Usually after about ten tries it deploys

```
    Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-gt_p5100-c1607e2b52fa88f
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\Yohannes\IdeaProjects\PaymentAssistant\out\production\PaymentAssistant\PaymentAssistant.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/tamru.yohannes.PaymentAssistant
Installing tamru.yohannes.PaymentAssistant
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/tamru.yohannes.PaymentAssistant"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/tamru.yohannes.PaymentAssistant
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
```

LogCat:

```
12-05 13:36:25.193    8332-8332/? E/cutils-trace﹕ Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="tamru.yohannes.PaymentAssistant"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:targetSdkVersion="15"
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        tools:ignore="OldTargetApi" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/assistant"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">

        <activity
            android:name="tamru.yohannes.PaymentAssistant.main.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="tamru.yohannes.PaymentAssistant.main.OCRCamera">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.OCRCamera"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="tamru.yohannes.PaymentAssistant.main.About"
            android:label="@string/about" />

        <activity
            android:name="tamru.yohannes.PaymentAssistant.main.Preferences"
            android:label="Preference" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Preferences"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="tamru.yohannes.PaymentAssistant.main.Transfer"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name="tamru.yohannes.PaymentAssistant.main.UserActions"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest and .java code?

Comment: @joostmakaay i've added the AndroidManifest file

Comment: For answers, try this [similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070816/failure-install-failed-invalid-apk)

Answer (score 3):

In my case (i have a rooted device) and when i rooted, something happened with my permission of /data/local/tmp and they have been changed, so adb can't get access  temp file. How i solved:
1. Install RootExplorer 
2. Create new "tmp" folder on sdcard 
3. Long press on tmp folder, and select Link to this folder (last option in menu)  
3. Go to /data/local/ and tap button CREATE LINK from bottom

Answer (score 1):

Please change your package name to be all lower case in your manifest and make sure your `android:name` attributes for your activities reflect the changes.

Comment: A full Java-language-style package name for the Android application. The name should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual package name parts may only start with letters. for more https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Answer (score -1):

Go to "Build" > "Clean Project". Works for me.