# Android Studio "install_failed_invalid_apk" error

Tags: android, android-studio

Im trying to debug a app in Android Studio, but every time i run the app to the phone it says:

```
Installing com.myapplication2.app
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.myapplication2.app"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.myapplication2.app
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
```

Looking to log

```
06-21 14:31:36.304    5407-5419/com.android.defcontainer W/zipro﹕ Unable to open zip    '/data/local/tmp/com.myapplication2.app': Permission denied
06-21 14:31:36.304    5407-5419/com.android.defcontainer D/asset﹕ failed to open Zip     archive '/data/local/tmp/com.myapplication2.app'
06-21 14:31:36.305    5407-5419/com.android.defcontainer W/PackageParser﹕ Unable to      read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/local/tmp/com.myapplication2.app
java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:455)
        at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:729)
        at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:173)
        at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:110)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-21 14:31:36.305    5407-5419/com.android.defcontainer W/DefContainer﹕ Failed to parse package
06-21 14:31:36.306      429-451/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.myapplication2.app
06-21 14:31:36.469      429-446/system_process V/Provider/Setting﹕ from settings cache , name = sys_free_storage_log_interval value = null
 06-21 14:31:36.469      429-446/system_process V/Provider/Setting﹕ from settings cache , name = disk_free_change_reporting_threshold value = null
```

Maybe the problem is related with "permission denied"? Tried to run Android Studio as Administrator, same issue. Using Windows 8.
I´m able to install the apk by copying to sdcard and installing directly from Android.

This started to happen after:
a) Updated my Android to a custom rom
b) Updated Android Studio from 0.4.6 to 0.5.2

But since both updates were simultaneously, cant say which one is responsible for this error.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it occurred after you flashed new ROM.

The system memory map altered which lead to permission issue of `/data/local/tmp/`.

The folder should be executable and readable with `shell` user.

Comment: Well that makes sense, but how can i change the permissions on this folder?

Comment: Did you see the answers to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070816/failure-install-failed-invalid-apk