# Unable to install apk through android studio on nexus 5/6.0.1 INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK

Tags: android, gradle

I am able to install the apk on a different device (galaxy nexus/kitkat) for the same configuration - studio/gradle 2.1.2, but it does not install on nexus 5 with marshmallow. I get an error with INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK.

Made sure the device does not have an existing installation of the same app. Cleared /data/local/tmp. Still the problem persists.

I have scanned through all such questions and tried the suggestions. None of them seem to work. My phone is not rooted.

**Update:**

This happens only on marshmallow. I tried on nexus-5 emulator with API 22 and it gets installed, nexus-5 emulator with API 23 however fails with INSTALL_FAILED_INVALIED_APK.

Any insights?

Comment: Try using Google first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failure \[INSTALL\_FAILED\_INVALID\_APK\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070816/failure-install-failed-invalid-apk)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Chisko. I have scanned through all such questions before posting and tried the suggestions. None of them seem to work - the one that I could not try was creating a symlink /data/local/tmp to sdcard and that is because I already have /data/local/tmp directory which I am not able to delete because of permissions. My device is not rooted.

Comment: I must emphasise that I am able to install the app on other devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out extractNativeLibs=false is not yet supported by the gradle plugin. Setting the value to true in AndroidManifest makes it work.

Hopefully a fix is coming soon - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172630