# Apk failing to install on Android N with INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK error

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I was trying to install apk with adb install but when I tried to install it I got the following error,

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/conform.src.com.conform-1: Package /data/app/conform.src.com.conform-1/base.apk code is missing]

Comment: How did you build the APK? If using Android Studio make sure that you are installing the full APK and not and "delta-APK" designed for patching an already installed app via InstantRun.

Comment: I build the apk using android sdk with command line tool in linux

Comment: I use aapt to create the apk

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62187743/551744

Answer (score 15):

I had the same trouble when installing AOSP built apks.

I did

> mm DEX_PREOPT_DEFAULT=nostripping

and it worked.

Comment: do you run this in the dev machine or in the android shell?

Comment: I tried running this command in both and the program 'mm' is missing

Comment: This works for me, so I added `export DEX_PREOPT_DEFAULT=nostripping` to my .profile

Answer (score 10):

I faced this error in react native after the gradle was updated. I did nothing except cleaning the project.

```
cd android
gradle clean
```

fixed my issue on windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I came upon with this problem.

After looking for [package_and_sign_apk](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually), I found that google is using [apksigner](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html) (instead of jarsigner)released after android-build-tools-24.0.3.

And I re-packaged my apk with command line(aapt),and signed with apksigner.

All work well.

Hope to help u some little~

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed this issue on my machine: windows.

Upgraded android studio (gradle upgraded as well as a result).

Had some minor issues with the manifest file as a result of AADT. Project installed and launched after.

Comment: Can you provide the version numbers?

Comment: Android Studio/Gradle 3.3, Android SDK Tools 26.1.1, Android Platform Version: API 28 rev 6. I simply installed the latest versions using SDK Manager

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I wanted to try out some java 8 features.
It started to work immediately after I removed this from my gradle file.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

> Note that this is probably not a solution when you're already using
>   java 8 features in your Android project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DexGuard obfuscator (like me), this issue can be caused by it. Updating DexGuard to latest version should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Solution:**

1. You need to create a blank app.
2. Open the the blank app's csproj file
3. copy the property group code for Debug, Debug-any cpu, release any cpu
4. Replace in your project's csproj file
5. Clean & Run

Cheers !!!

Comment: Please don't post same answer on multiple old post .

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was missing storage in my device. Deleting some files enabled me to continue installation.