# App does not overwrite the already existing app

Tags: android

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pvijayalakshmi.previousversion">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

grade file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pvijayalakshmi.previousversion"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I have developed an application. And I have installed it on my phone.

Now I have a requirement of adding one column to the my application. I have added one column to the database. I have made changes to the `onUpgrade()`. I have changed the database version from 1 to 2.

I have changed the version code and version name in `gradle` file.

I don't want to uninstall the app and re installing. I want to upgrade the app automatically.

Now I am trying to install my application(after adding column to database) in phone where previous application is also existed.

I need to upgrade my previously existed application. But I am facing issue here. The present app does not overwrite the previous application. Both applications packages names are same here.

How can I overcome this. I need the programmatic solution.

For example we have many apps like whatsapp. They have made changes to the app and releases. So, we directly update to the new version with out uninstalling our existing whatsapp. Like wise I am trying to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

When I am trying to install application, It is showing like this.

[image]

Comment: just uninstall the app and run it again.

Comment: You are using in MI Brand Mobile?

Comment: I don't want to uninstall and re-install my application again. I want to overwrite the previous application.@HemantParmar

Comment: No, moto g4 plus@Raja

Comment: is your applicationId in gradle is same as in AndroidManifest file?

Comment: @bhavana, you already made version changes in gradle, also re-check Manifest in case you have some version mentioned and not updated. Eg. You might be using productFlavors.

Comment: see my updated post it will help you

Comment: yes, same sir @Sunny

Comment: see here for more solution https://stackoverflow.com/q/19070816/909317

Comment: If I do clean project, It will work . But I don't want to do this in this way. I need to do programmatically.

Comment: @bhavana share your  app gradle and manifest file.

Comment: I have shared the gradle and manifest file.@HemantParmar

Comment: Please any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android App Not Install. An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959890/android-app-not-install-an-existing-package-by-the-same-name-with-a-conflicting)

This answer works for me thank you so much for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Developer Options in under mobile setting option

then, Enable these all are

1. USB Debugging
2. Install Via USB
3. Verify apps over USB

these all are should be enable mode(checked mode)

then you have to try..

Comment: All these options are in Enable mode @Raja

Comment: Sir, do you have any solution?@Raja

Answer (score 0):

1. you can check sure to uninstall once.
2. you can clear cache on your phone.after that switch off the phone you can try again install.
3. if the above not worked can  you try creating signed APK file and install that once.
4. clear the project once again...

Comment: Sir, I don't want to uninstall my app. I want to update the app.

Answer (score 0):

If your existing i.e installed app in phone is **signed APK** then to overwrite the new APK on it means without uninstall old one run new APK , you have to install signed APK of new one in sdcard and after that install that. **It will work.**

Comment: It is not the new APK. It is also having the same package. @Dharmishtha

Comment: @bhavana new APK means new versionName and versionCode of app . of course same package name.

Comment: For example we have many apps like whatsapp. They have made changes to the app and releases. So, we directly update to the new version with out uninstalling our existing whatsapp. Like wise I am trying to do. Please help me.

Comment: @bhavana yes this is exactly what you want.

Comment: How to install in sdcard?@Dharmishtha

Comment: I didn't get your answer,sorry@Dharmishtha

Comment: just create signed APK then from that place (where signed APK is created) copy and paste in your phone . and then by clicking on that APK from your phone ,it will ask to install .

Answer (score 0):

You might want to disable instant run `Android Studio Settings or Preferences-> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run.`

[image]

**clean** and **rebuild** the project again

if you are using miui phone then Turn Off MIUI optimization

`Settings --> Additional settings --> Developer options --> Turn Off MIUI optimization`