# INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK too many times

Tags: android

I am working on a live android project. When I try to run the app, it is giving me `INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK` error. I clean the project and rerun, then it works. But after 4-5 times of run, it gives me the same error again.

[image]

It is so annoying to clean and rerun too many times.

Note: project is a little big that it takes around a minute to clean and build.

What is the reason and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Try disabling instant run

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Yeah, if I disable instant run, it works. But is there any way to solve it withot disabling it?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070816/failure-install-failed-invalid-apk may be one of the solution will helps you