# problem with running flutter app in vscode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, adb

when I run my app I get this error :

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install F:\flutter-project\1\third_app\third_app\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.example.third_app-1: Package /data/app/com.example.third_app-1/base.apk code is missing]
Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86.
```

update: 
I run `flutter clear` in the terminal and after restarting my computer and executing again, the problem solved

Comment: what do you see if you try `flutter run -v` command from the terminal? (for example last 10-20 lines)

Comment: i get a long text start with  this: 
[  +21 ms] executing: [F:\flutter\] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +44 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty...
...

Comment: (for example last 10-20 lines)

Comment: [  +14 ms] C:\Users\S.Radman\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +37 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.

Comment: I get these errors after I trying to use shareperefernces in my app ,

Comment: ] > Task :shared_preferences_web:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :shared_preferences_web:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE

Comment: why dont you simply post those last 20 lines of the output in your question?

Comment: ok I edit my post, and add an image of the result of running flutter run -v

Comment: i dont mean "DEBUG CONSOLE" tab - i mean "TERMINAL" tab - please dont post any images: instead use copy/paste and post the full output of `flutter run -v` output

Comment: I add another image from "TERMINAL" tab

Comment: checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19070939/7924072

Comment: this answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/57770441/2064295

Answer (score 0):

One of the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57770441) mentioned in the comment:

> For Flutter projects, with VS Code editor, go to the project source
> folder and delete the "build" folder and start debugging.

This could also be attained by running `flutter clean` from the terminal. This command helps you delete build cache which is in the `/build` folder. You can always uses this command when there are any bugs in the build process.