# Session 'app': Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK

Tags: android, appdynamics

Hello good morning community, I am somewhat confused, I am integrating the Cisco AppDynamics tool, when performing the integration as mentioned in the documentation and when running the project it throws the following error.

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK
The APKs are invalid.
Retry
```

Event Log:

```
Session 'app': Installation did not succeed.
                The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK
                Retry
```

build.gradel:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
 buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    classpath 'com.appdynamics:appdynamics-gradle-plugin:4.5.+'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }
  allprojects {
   repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

  }
}
   task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradel(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'adeum'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "mx.com.hdi.autoseguro.appdynamics"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
```

dependencies {

```
implementation 'com.appdynamics:appdynamics-runtime:4.5.+'
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to `Build > Clean Project` ? and even `File > Invalid Caches/ Restart...` ? otherwise you can check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070816/failure-install-failed-invalid-apk

Comment: Yes, I have been reading and reviewing, the strange thing is when I remove the entire implementation of AppDynamics, the project is working normally, I do not understand if I am implementing something wrong.

Comment: you should avoid notation like '4.5.+' and target a direct version because it may cause bugs like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the AppDynamics plugin and gradle plugin tools 3.6.x. You can see this link: https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/End-User-Monitoring-EUM/AppDynamic-EUM-setup-for-Android-Cordova-project/td-p/38864

I have downgrade gradle plugin tools to 3.5.x and solve it